# SSH MOTD per user

Tags: linux, ssh, banner, motd

I want to display banner (welcome message) for SSH users with a specific welcome message for each user.

Answer (score 48):

*You did not specify, what SSH server are you using. I'm assuming OpenSSH.*

Note that the SSH banner and the MOTD are two different things.

While almost indistinguishable in an SSH terminal, they have a different behavior, for example, in an SFTP client.

---

The MOTD is just a text printed on an interactive terminal. So, it won't (and cannot) be sent to SFTP clients, for example (more about that later).

The MOTD is hard-coded to the `/etc/motd` in OpenSSH. You can turn it on/off globally only, using the `PrintMotd` directive.

On some Linux systems, however, the `PrintMotd` is always off and the MOTD is printed by the PAM stack instead (using the `pam_motd` module). In this case you can turn it off via the `/etc/pam.d/sshd` or specify a custom `motd=` path as a module parameter.

---

The SSH banner is a special SSH 2.0 feature, sent in a specific SSH packet (SSH2_MSG_USERAUTH_BANNER).

As such, even non-terminal clients, like SFTP clients, can process it and display to user. See how [the banner displays in WinSCP SFTP/SCP client](https://winscp.net/eng/docs/ui_authenticate#authentication_banner) for example.

The SSH banner is configurable per user (or group or other criteria) in the [`sshd_config`](https://man.openbsd.org/sshd_config) using the [`Banner`](https://man.openbsd.org/sshd_config#Banner) and the [`Match` directives](https://man.openbsd.org/sshd_config#Match):

```
Match User username1
    Banner /etc/banner_user1

Match User username2
    Banner /etc/banner_user2
```

See also [Disable ssh banner for specific users or ips](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/96975/119732).

---

Of course, you can also use a custom implementation for the message/banner. Simply print a message selected using your custom logic from a global profile script.

As with the MOTD, this won't work for non-interactive sessions (the SFTP and alike).

More importantly, not only it won't work, *you need to make sure* that you print the message for an interactive terminal only. What OpenSSH does automatically for the `/etc/motd`. Either use a global profile script that executes for an interactive terminal only, or print the message conditionally based on value of the `TERM` environment variable.

If you print the message for non-interactive session, you break any client that uses a strict protocol, such as the SFTP or the SCP, as the client will try to interpret your text message as a protocol message, failing badly.

See for example [description of such issue in documentation of WinSCP SFTP/SCP client](https://winscp.net/eng/docs/message_large_packet).

*(I'm the author of WinSCP)*

Comment: Hi all thanks for reply, I got the solution please correct me if i am wrong. I append this lines into /etc/profile file.  PGROUP=`groups|awk '{print $1}'`
cat /etc/motd.${PGROUP}  before adding this line i create banner file for each user under /etc directory. and file like motd.root and motd.alex and this work for me.

Comment: That should do too. Except as per my answer, this works in an interactive terminal only. It won't work for SFTP and similar.

Comment: interactive terminal means ?

Comment: It's a terminal that a human interacts with (as opposite to SFTP session, SCP session or non-interactive terminal used for remote execution of some batch task)

Comment: I have included some tricky details about custom implementation of the banner.

Comment: I'm pretty sure `/etc/profile` is not only executed for interactive shells.

Comment: @nyuszika7h I understood as much from Bash man page. But it's not clear definitely. So I'm better removing that note.

Answer (score 12):

You can use `"$HOME/.ssh/rc"` file too for archive what you want to do

```
echo "echo Hello World" > /home/pluto/.ssh/rc
ssh pluto@localhost
Last login: Thu Dec 18 08:46:16 2014 from localhost.localdomain
Hello World
```

So, you can have one ssh rc for every user.

Comment: hi, I try this but it gives error message .ssh/rc: 1: .ssh/rc: welcom: not found.

Comment: was my fault, i did a typo, you need echo like in normal bash script

Comment: "Wolrd" is also a typo :)

Comment: I get "stty: standard input: Inappropriate ioctl for device".

Comment: what do you have in .ssh/rc?

Comment: "The shell script /etc/sshrc is invoked by the SSH server for each incoming SSH connection. [...] You may define a similar script in your account, ~/.ssh/rc (SSH1, OpenSSH) or ~/.ssh2/rc (SSH2), to be invoked for every SSH connection to your account. If this file exists, /etc/sshrc isn't run. The SSH rc file is much like a shell startup file (e.g., ~/.profile or ~/.cshrc), but it executes only when your account is accessed by SSH. It is run for both interactive logins and remote commands." From [O'REILLY - SSH: The Secure Shell](https://docstore.mik.ua/orelly/networking_2ndEd/ssh/ch08_04.htm)