# SSH connection refused/error message

Tags: linux, ssh, login, ubuntu-14.04, login-script

I have a systems which has multiple users but only few selected users are allowed to login to the system at a given time through SSH (or otherwise).

I am using "passwd  -l/-u" command to lock and unlock users, and allow only one user at a time.

What I need is to tell the other users trying to SSH to a system why they cannot SSH. Currently when the user account is locked and they cannot SSH they only get "Connection Refused" message. I want to be able to edit this message to tell them "Your account is locked and you cannot login before xxxxxxx time"

What are the possible ways I can achieve this. I have tried googling for this but without any luck.

Thanks.

Comment: http://serverfault.com/questions/653399/ssh-motd-per-user Look for the section on SSH banner per user.  You could probably script something off that.

Comment: If you want to customize the message but not per-user you can use `nologin`, meaning re-enabling users account but assigning them `/usr/bin/nologin` as their login shell. They will not be able to connect and receive a default message saying the account is disabled or the message written in `/etc/nologin.txt`. If you want a per-user message you can replace nologin by a hand-made script which always returns 1.

Comment: @piernov : thanks. I think that works for me. I found a reference online which suggests the same approach as you did. :)

Comment: @piernov that should probably be an answer.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you want to customize the message but not per-user you can use `nologin`, meaning re-enabling users account but assigning them `/usr/bin/nologin` as their login shell. They will not be able to connect and receive a default message saying the account is disabled or the message written in `/etc/nologin.txt`.

If you want a per-user message you can replace `nologin` with a hand-made script which always returns 1.