# powershell detect login is sftp

Tags: windows, ssh, powershell, sftp, winscp

***tl;dr*** in powershell, how can I detect a login is *specifically* SFTP and not SSH or local?

On Windows 10 I have the built-in OpenSSH service running. For SFTP protocol connections, the server uses the typical `sftp-server`, i.e. the `sshd_config` reads

```text
Subsystem    sftp  sftp-server.exe
```

The default login shell is powershell.exe. That default powershell.exe login sources `$PROFILE` which I have modified to print some helpful startup information.  However, printing that helpful startup information causes SFTP connections to fail. e.g. when I connect WinSCP to the OpenSSH service it fails to connect with popup error that reads

```text
Received too large (1127898197 B) SFTP packet. Max supported packet size is 1024000 B.

Cannot initialize SFTP protocol. Is the host running an SFTP server?
```

[image: WinSCP SFTP login failure]

I found via experimentation that this error is due to messages printed when the Powershell instance executes `$PROFILE`. Or to say in other words, if I prevent any `Write-Host` calls in the `$PROFILE` then WinSCP successfully completes the connection.  Also, it does not appear due to printing too much. It appears that printing *anything* from `$PROFILE` causes WinSCP connections to fail. Also, similar errors happen when using other SFTP clients like `lftp` and `termscp` so it's not an issue with WinSCP.

I'd like to have the powershell script at `$PROFILE` `break` early when it detects an SFTP login (and not call `Write-Host`). I'd like the `$PROFILE` run to complete for all other logins (SSH, local, etc.).

Is there a way to detect an SFTP login within powershell?

[Original post on StackOverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/q/77304474/471376) (closed).

Answer (score 0):

you can add a conditional statement in your $PROFILE script to skip any output commands if the session is detected as SFTP. For example, you can use something like this:

```
# Check if this is an SFTP session
$IsSFTP = $env:SSH_ORIGINAL_COMMAND -eq "sftp-server.exe"

# Execute the rest of the $PROFILE script only if this is not an SFTP session
if (-not $IsSFTP) {
    # Your original $PROFILE script goes here
    Write-Host "Welcome to PowerShell"
    # ...
}
```

Comment: I cannot find that environment variable `SSH_ORIGINAL_COMMAND ` in the SFTP session. Do you know where it comes from?

Comment: @JamesThomasMoon It is set by sshd. But I believe this answer is wrong. The variable is not set in this scenario. I've already pointed you to https://serverfault.com/q/653399/168875 – Did you check `TERM` as suggested there? (tbh, I'm not sure `TERM` is relevant on Windows, but it's at least wroth trying).